# What's the problem with the index as a key?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have to go through a json and render some of the json data on the front, I shared it on a forum. Is there any simpler way?  Or because it is json, since it will always return the same number of values, I shouldn't worry about scaling?

```
{apiResponseData && (
        <section className={styles.slaZabbix}>
          {apiResponseData.result?.sli[0]?.map((sliItem, index) => (
            <section key={index} >
              <p>Uptime: {sliItem.uptime}</p>
              <p>Downtime: {sliItem.downtime}</p>
              <h3>SLI: {sliItem.sli}%</h3>
              <p>Error Budget: {sliItem.error_budget}</p>
            </section>
          ))}
        </section>
      )}
```

I tried to call each element individually, but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure of the JSON is consistent and you want to avoid repeating the code for each element, you can make your code more concise and scalable.
Each **sliItem** in your array has properties like uptime, downtime, sli, and error_budget.

```
{apiResponseData?.result?.sli[0] && (
  <section className={styles.slaZabbix}>
    {apiResponseData.result.sli[0].map((sliItem, index) => (
      <section key={index}>
        {Object.entries(sliItem).map(([key, value]) => (
          <p key={key}>
            {key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)}: {value}
          </p>
        ))}
      </section>
    ))}
  </section>
)}
```

This is possible only if you are sure that your json will be consistent always.

Comment: But what if I only want one of the elements?

Comment: By only one, you mean like only uptime or only downtime?

Comment: just one element of the apiResponseData.result.sli response. It has 4 elements for example and I just want to use 1. I tried to change the index by putting it in the index of the element I want but I was unsuccessful

Comment: No, if you have specific requirements and want to work with only certain part of data then this dynamic approach won't work. It only works if you want consistent data always like I said earlier. Either you have to change the array as per your requirements before starting, or go as per your earlier approach.

Comment: I understand, so my code is "right" for the current context? Thank you, I will use your answer when the time comes.